# Getting error to fit a Conv1d to classify diabetic patients using the Pima Indian diabetes data set using keras in R

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am new to the machine learning field. I was using keras package in R to classify the diabetic individuals, using the Pima Indian diabetes dataset and fitting a Conv1d. I am not sure where I am doing the mistake, but getting some errors.

1:8 columns are the features and the 9th column is our label coded as 0 and 1.

The data dimensions are as follows:

```
dim (data)=(768,9)#Main data dimension

dim (training)=(534, 8)#Training set dimension

dim (test)=(234,8)#Testing set dimension
```

Please help me to identify the bug. Thanks in advance.

```
data=read.csv(file.choose(), header=T)


data=as.matrix(data)
head(data)
dimnames(data)=NULL
str(data)

#Data Normalization
data[, 1:8]=normalize(data[, 1:8])
summary(data)


#Data Partition 
set.seed(1234) 

ind=sample(2, nrow(data), replace=T, prob=c(0.7,0.3))
training=data[ind==1, 1:8]
test=data[ind==2, 1:8]
trainingtarget=data[ind==1, 9]
testtarget=data[ind==2, 9]


# reshape
dim(training) <- c(nrow(training), 8, 1)
dim(test) <- c(nrow(test), 8, 1)

dim(trainingtarget) <- c(nrow(trainingtarget), 1, 1)
dim(testtarget) <- c(nrow(testtarget), 1, 1)



cnn_bc_model <- keras_model_sequential()

cnn_bc_model %>%
  layer_conv_1d(filter=32, kernel_size=5, padding="same", input_shape=c(8,1)) %>%
  layer_activation("relu") %>%

  layer_conv_1d(filter=32, kernel_size=3) %>%
  layer_activation("relu") %>%

  layer_max_pooling_1d(pool_size=2) %>%
  layer_dropout(0.2) %>%

  layer_dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')

cnn_bc_model %>% compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='nadam', metrics = c('accuracy'))
cnn_bc_history <- cnn_bc_model %>% fit(training, trainingtarget, epochs=100, 
                                       batch_size=8, validation_split=0.2)

#Now evaluate the model with our test data set
cnn_bc_model %>%
  evaluate(test, testLabels)
```

Error:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: A target array with shape (534, 1, 1) was passed for output of shape (None, 3, 1) while using as loss `binary_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the shape of the `max_pooling_1d` layer. For your specific model you have the following layer shapes.

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_3 (Conv1D)            (None, 8, 32)             192       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)    (None, 8, 32)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_4 (Conv1D)            (None, 6, 32)             3104      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_5 (Activation)    (None, 6, 32)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_2 (MaxPooling1 (None, 3, 32)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 3, 32)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 3, 1)              33        
_________________________________________________________________
activation_6 (Activation)    (None, 3, 1)              0         
=================================================================
Total params: 3,329
Trainable params: 3,329
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

The output shape of your network is `(None,3,1)` that do not match the target shape previously defined `(None,1,1)`. To solve that issue, you can add a `layer_flatten` layer to your model between the `max_pooling_1d`layer and the `dropout`layer.

```
max_pooling1d_3 (MaxPooling1 (None, 3, 32)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 96)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 96)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 97        
_________________________________________________________________
activation_9 (Activation)    (None, 1)                 0
```

Or you can add the `layer_flatten` after the last `dense` layer and add another `dense`layer.

```
activation_12 (Activation)   (None, 3, 1)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_2 (Flatten)          (None, 3)                 0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 4         
_________________________________________________________________
activation_13 (Activation)   (None, 1)                 0
```

If you have difficult to keep track of all the layer shapes, try to add `summary(cnn_bc_model)`before you start to train the model so you can debug any shape related issue. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I tried both ways as you suggested but still getting an error. I have used the following code.

```
data=read.csv(file.choose(), header=T)


data=as.matrix(data)
head(data)
dimnames(data)=NULL
str(data)

#Data Normalization
data[, 1:8]=normalize(data[, 1:8])
summary(data)


#Data Partition 
set.seed(1234) 

ind=sample(2, nrow(data), replace=T, prob=c(0.7,0.3))
training=data[ind==1, 1:8]
test=data[ind==2, 1:8]
trainingtarget=data[ind==1, 9]
testtarget=data[ind==2, 9]


# reshape
dim(training) <- c(nrow(training), 8, 1)
dim(test) <- c(nrow(test), 8, 1)

dim(trainingtarget) <- c(534, 1, 1)#534 is the length of this series
dim(testtarget) <- c(234, 1, 1)#234 is the length of this series


cnn_bc_model <- keras_model_sequential()
cnn_bc_model %>%
  layer_conv_1d(filter=32, kernel_size=5, input_shape=c(8,1)) %>%
  layer_activation("relu") %>%
  layer_conv_1d(filter=32, kernel_size=3) %>%
  layer_activation("relu") %>%
  layer_max_pooling_1d(pool_size=2) %>%
  layer_flatten() %>%
  layer_dropout(0.2) %>%
  layer_dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid') %>%
  layer_activation("softmax")

summary(cnn_bc_model)

cnn_bc_model %>% compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='nadam', metrics = c('accuracy'))
cnn_bc_history <- cnn_bc_model %>% fit(training, trainingtarget, epochs=100, 
                                       batch_size=8, validation_split=0.2)

#Now evaluate the model with our test data set
cnn_bc_model %>%
  evaluate(test, testLabels)
```

The error looks different now as follows:

Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  InvalidArgumentError: Cannot update variable with shape [] using a Tensor with shape [8], shapes must be equal.
     [[{{node metrics_22/acc/AssignAddVariableOp}}]]

Comment: Hi, 
The problem has been solved. Thank you so much for your help. Actually, before reshaping the dimensions of the data, we need to apply one hot encoding (Although I am not sure why do we need to code it in that way since the label has already 2 categories 0 and 1). Fortunately, it is working now. And I am able to run other networks as well.

# one-hot encoding is as follows:
y_train_lab <- to_categorical(trainingtarget)
y_test_lab <- to_categorical(testtarget)